# Accessing specific meta fields from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, meta

I am using the following to output meta values for a current logged in user.

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$key = 'chargebee_user_subscriptions';
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, true  );
print_r($all_meta_for_user);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [subscription_id] => IaQX8AtBRo [product_id] => cbdemo_grow [product_name] => Plan - Grow [product_decs] => This a 3-month plan with a 14 day trial period. [status] => in_trial [product_price] => 89 USD / 3 month [trail_start] => 08/02/2018 [trial_end] => 22/02/2018 ) )
```

This works great, but I only need to access a specific meta field from the array `product_id`.

I've attempted to output this via the following but cannot get it to work:

```
<?php
$all_meta_for_user['product_id'][0];
```

Comment: please do a little debug work before posting here (with `print_r` or `echo`), as you could have easily found the mistake in $all_meta_for_user (array indexes swapped).

Comment: Will do, apologies got it sorted now :)

Comment: @Pierre, he did do some debugging. As you can see he even posted it. 
(`Array ( [0] => Array ( [subscription_id] => IaQX8AtBRo [product_id] => cbdemo_grow [product_name] => Plan - Grow [product_decs] => This a 3-month plan with a 14 day trial period. [status] => in_trial [product_price] => 89 USD / 3 month [trail_start] => 08/02/2018 [trial_end] => 22/02/2018 ) )
`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it the wrong way around.

```
$all_meta_for_user[0]['product_id'];
```

Comment: Doh! That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are accessing the array in a wrong way. Try the following:

```
$all_meta_for_user[0]['product_id'];
```